# retain attributes and classes when subsetting (rrapply?)

Tags: r, subset

From `?"["` in the details section:

*Subsetting (except by an empty index) will drop all attributes except names, dim and dimnames.*

Example:

```
myobj <- structure(list(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c(4, 5, 6)), class = "myclass")
attr(myobj, "someattr") <- "Hello World"
myobj
# $a
# [1] 1 2 3

# $b
# [1] 4 5 6

# attr(,"class")
# [1] "myclass"
# attr(,"someattr")
# [1] "Hello World"
```

So if I subset the first position the attributes and classes are dropped:

```
myobj[-c(2)]
# $a
# [1] 1 2 3
```

The solution is to create a `method`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486342/subset-drops-attributes-on-vectors-how-to-maintain-persist-them) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610072/retain-a-class-attribute-of-an-r-object-when-subsetting).

The solution is quite old though and I was wondering are there simpler/quicker ways to do this now so you dont have to create a method? `rrapply` comes to mind but I think it only works to recursively apply a function `f` to a set of elements of a list:

```
library(rrapply)
rrapply(myobj,  f = head, n = 1, how = "list")
# $a
# [1] 1

# $b
# [1] 4

# attr(,"class")
# [1] "myclass"
# attr(,"someattr")
# [1] "Hello World"
```

Is there a way to use `rrapply` to subset in the way I want to preserve the attributes and class or is there a simpler way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1) gv** Try get_vars (can be shortened to gv) in the collapse package:

```
library(collapse)
gv(myobj, -2)
```

giving:

```
$a
[1] 1 2 3

attr(,"class")
[1] "myclass"
attr(,"someattr")
[1] "Hello World"
```

**2) Base R** or NULL out the components you don't want:

```
replace(myobj, 2, NULL)
```

giving:

```
$a
[1] 1 2 3

attr(,"class")
[1] "myclass"
attr(,"someattr")
[1] "Hello World"
```

**3) rrapply**  We can use rrapply with how = "prune" .  The condition ensures that only components at the first level with the indicated names are returned.

```
library(rrapply)
cond <- function(x, .xname, .xpos) .xname %in% names(myobj)[-2] && .xpos == 1
rrapply(myobj, condition = cond, how="prune")
```

giving:

```
$a
[1] 1 2 3

attr(,"class")
[1] "myclass"
attr(,"someattr")
[1] "Hello World"
```