# Why does adding attributes to a dataframe take longer with large dataframes?

Tags: r

Let’s make a simple dataframe and give it an attribute “foo”:

```r
orig <- data.frame(x1 = 1, x2 = 2)
attr(orig, "foo") <- TRUE
```

“foo” is there:

```r
attributes(orig)
#> $names
#> [1] "x1" "x2"
#> 
#> $class
#> [1] "data.frame"
#> 
#> $row.names
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $foo
#> [1] TRUE
```

But if I reorder the columns, “foo” disappears

```r
new <- orig[, c(2, 1)]
attributes(new)
#> $names
#> [1] "x2" "x1"
#> 
#> $class
#> [1] "data.frame"
#> 
#> $row.names
#> [1] 1
```

I could add it back with:

```r
attributes(new) <- utils::modifyList(attributes(orig), attributes(new))
attributes(new)
#> $names
#> [1] "x2" "x1"
#> 
#> $class
#> [1] "data.frame"
#> 
#> $row.names
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $foo
#> [1] TRUE
```

But this operation is time consuming. Not in this case because it’s a
one-row dataframe, but consider this case with 10,000,000 rows:

```r
orig <- data.frame(x1 = rep(1, 1e7), x2 = rep(2, 1e7))
attr(orig, "foo") <- TRUE
new <- orig[, c(2, 1)]

bench::mark(
  test = {
    attributes(new) <- utils::modifyList(attributes(orig), attributes(new))
  }
)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 test         43.2ms   46.6ms      21.6    38.1MB     14.4
```

Of course, it doesn't take *that* much time to make this, but it is much longer than in the first case with one row (which takes only a few microseconds). It seems weird to me that the time needed to add a single attribute to a dataframe increases with the size of the dataframe. Am I missing something? Is there a more efficient way to add a list of "simple" attributes to a large dataframe?

Edit: looking for a solution with base R only

Comment: I wonder if if the memory allocated for the data frame doesn't include space for attributes, so the data is copied when you first add one.

Comment: Thanks for the extra effort and investigation, it is much appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason the computation time of copying all `data.frame` attributes scales with the size of the `data.frame` seems to be mainly due to the `row.names` attribute.

We can check that copying the `row.names` attribute is responsible for most of the computation time:

```
orig <- data.frame(x1 = rep(1, 1e7), x2 = rep(2, 1e7))
attr(orig, "foo") <- TRUE
new <- orig[, c(2, 1)]

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  all_attrs = { attributes(new) <- attributes(orig) },
  rownames = { attr(new, "row.names") <- attr(orig, "row.names") },
  foo = { attr(new, "foo") <- attr(orig, "foo") },
  times = 10,
  unit = "ms"  
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>       expr       min       lq       mean     median        uq        max neval
#>  all_attrs 60.477554 61.18414 64.3562408 61.9978505 67.117645  72.827139    10
#>   rownames 59.831147 61.21029 69.6012781 64.2950890 68.880676 106.280348    10
#>        foo  0.001043  0.00206  0.0072771  0.0087225  0.011206   0.015295    10
```

If we compare this to copying the `foo` attribute in the case of the small `data.frame`, the timing is (roughly) of the same order:

```
orig <- data.frame(x1 = 1, x2 = 2)
attr(orig, "foo") <- TRUE
new <- orig[, c(2, 1)]

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  foo = { attr(new, "foo") <- attr(orig, "foo") },
  unit = "ms"
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>  expr     min      lq       mean    median        uq      max neval
#>   foo 0.00115 0.00118 0.00146262 0.0012055 0.0012725 0.022368   100
```

To be efficient you can choose to only copy any custom defined attributes (instead of all `data.frame` attributes). For instance:

```
## replace only custom attributes
replace_attrs <- function(obj, new_attrs) {
  for(nm in setdiff(names(new_attrs), names(attributes(data.frame())))) {
    attr(obj, which = nm) <- new_attrs[[nm]]
  }
  return(obj)
}

new <- replace_attrs(new, attributes(orig))
```

Answer (score 11):

### Row names are stored lazily in a data frame but when copied they are fully evaluated

I have extensively updated this answer as I realised that I had reached an incorrect conclusion using `tracemem()` to consider the memory location of objects, but not considering the object size. Instead, I use a [helper function](https://gist.github.com/samrickman/388a0278bf427b52668f5f0bd4ddefe2) to create a simplified, tree representation of the output of `lobstr::sxp(dat)` to show how objects are represented in memory. The conclusion is that it is unnecessary to pre-allocate `row.names`, and that simply avoiding copying them as described in the excellent answer by Joris C. is sufficient.

#### tl;dr: never copy the row names attribute

When you create a data frame of `n` rows without explicitly declaring the row names, the row names are stored as an integer vector of length 2 of the form `c(NA, -n)`.

If you copy the row names attribute from one data frame to another, R evaluates this vector in order to copy it. This should never be done.

Alternatively you could use `data.table` or `tidyverse`, both of which keep attributes when a copy is made, avoiding the need to copy anything.

### A closer look at what happens in memory

Let's create a data frame with 10 rows.

```r
num_rows  <- 10
set.seed(0)
dat  <- data.frame(
    x_char = sample(letters, num_rows),
    x_int = sample(1:10, num_rows)
)
```

Let's look at how it appears in memory:

```r
library(lobstr)
dat_sxp  <- sxp(dat)
get_dat_obj_tree(dat_sxp)
1 dat    VECSXP    length: 2     mem_addr:0x7
2  ¦--x_char    STRSXP    length: 10     mem_addr:0x1
3  ¦--x_int    INTSXP    length: 10     mem_addr:0x2
4  °--_attrib    LISTSXP    length: 3     mem_addr:0x3
5      ¦--names    STRSXP    length: 2     mem_addr:0x4
6      ¦--class    STRSXP    length: 1     mem_addr:0x5
7      °--row.names    INTSXP    length: 2     mem_addr:0x6
```

The function replaces the memory addresses with unique integers (i.e. `mem_addr:0x1` will remain the address of `x_char` every time the real address is looked up, unless the memory location of `x_char` actually changes).

We would expect the data to have length 10. But why are the `row.names` only length 2? Let's print them:

```r
rownames(dat) # "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10"
attr(dat, "row.names") #  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Clearly these are vectors with length 10. You might notice that one is a character vector and one is an integer vector. This led me down a lot of dead-ends, until I found this [comment](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/base/R/dataframe.R#L21) in the R source code:

```r
## As from R 2.4.0, row.names can be either character or integer.
## row.names() will always return character.
## attr(, "row.names") will return either character or integer.
##
## Do not assume that the internal representation is either, since
## 1L:n is stored as the integer vector c(NA, n) to save space (and
## the C-level code to get/set the attribute makes the appropriate
## translations.
```

This reminded me of something you often see in reproducible examples:

```r
dput(dat)
# structure(list(x_char = c("e", "i", "n", "z", "w", "b", "j",
# "l", "o", "a"), x_int = c(4L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 10L, 5L, 8L, 9L,
# 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

We see that row names are indeed represented as a vector of length 2, `row.names = c(NA, -10L)`. This is the key to understanding how to avoid the expensive copy operation.

#### How does creating a new attribute change things?

It doesn't. It simply creates a circumstance where you are more likely to copy row names, as attributes are not copied after every operation. [R Internals](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html) states:

> Subsetting (other than by an empty index) generally drops all attributes except names, dim and dimnames which are reset as appropriate.

Let's create a new attribute, `foo`, and see what happens in memory:

```r
attr(dat, "foo")  <- TRUE
```

Let's look at the internal representation:

```r
dat_foo_sxp  <- sxp(dat)
get_dat_obj_tree(dat_foo_sxp)
1 dat    VECSXP    length: 2     mem_addr:0x7
2  ¦--x_char    STRSXP    length: 10     mem_addr:0x1
3  ¦--x_int    INTSXP    length: 10     mem_addr:0x2
4  °--_attrib    LISTSXP    length: 4     mem_addr:0x3
5      ¦--names    STRSXP    length: 2     mem_addr:0x4
6      ¦--class    STRSXP    length: 1     mem_addr:0x5
7      ¦--row.names    INTSXP    length: 2     mem_addr:0x6
8      °--foo    LGLSXP    length: 1     mem_addr:0x8
```

Nothing has truly changed in memory - the attributes class simply has a new node, of type `LGLSXP`, i.e. a logical vector.

#### What happens when we subset the data frame?

Let's re-order the columns.

```r
new  <- dat[, c(2,1)]
```

Although we have selected all the columns, we are essentially subsetting the data by index. Let's look at the nodes of the object in memory:

```r
new_sxp  <- sxp(new)
get_dat_obj_tree(new_sxp, "new")
1 new    VECSXP    length: 2     mem_addr:0x12
2  ¦--x_int    INTSXP    length: 10     mem_addr:0x2
3  ¦--x_char    STRSXP    length: 10     mem_addr:0x1
4  °--_attrib    LISTSXP    length: 3     mem_addr:0x9
5      ¦--names    STRSXP    length: 2     mem_addr:0x10
6      ¦--class    STRSXP    length: 1     mem_addr:0x5
7      °--row.names    INTSXP    length: 2     mem_addr:0x11
```

This is broadly what we would expect from a lazily-evaluated copy apart from the `row.names`, which have not changed but have a new memory address:

1. The data frame itself has a new memory address.
2. The memory address of the `integer` column is the same.
3. The memory address of the `character` column is the same.
4. The attributes [pairlist](https://github.com/hadley/r-internals/blob/master/pairlists.md) has a new memory address.
5. The `names` have a new new location (because it's re-ordered).
6. The `class` has the same address.
7. The `row.names` have a new memory address.

Perhaps R could have kept the `row.names` in the same memory location. After all, we are only subsetting columns, so the number and order of rows is unchanged.

However, **and this is why my previous suggestion to pre-allocate the row names was wrong**, the fact that there are new `row.names` does not significantly affect execution time. R is creating a new integer vector of length 2, regardless of the size of the data. This takes almost no time. It is probably not worth adding logic to the R source to establish whether the rows are the same, in order to avoid such a tiny operation.

#### So why does the example in the question take longer with larger data frames?

It is notable in your example, and the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74031453/12545041) by Joris C., that operations take longer if they include `attr(new, "row.names") <- attr(dat, "row.names")`, either individually or as part of a larger function call such as `utils::modifyList(attributes(dat), attributes(new))`. Let's try the simple way:

```r
attr(new, "row.names") <- attr(dat, "row.names")
get_dat_obj_tree(sxp(new))
1 dat    VECSXP    length: 2     mem_addr:0x15
2  ¦--x_int    INTSXP    length: 10     mem_addr:0x2
3  ¦--x_char    STRSXP    length: 10     mem_addr:0x1
4  °--_attrib    LISTSXP    length: 3     mem_addr:0x13
5      ¦--names    STRSXP    length: 2     mem_addr:0x10
6      ¦--class    STRSXP    length: 1     mem_addr:0x5
7      °--row.names    INTSXP    length: 2     mem_addr:0x14
```

There's a new memory address. But the `row.names` attribute of `new` is still an integer vector of length 2. If we run `dput(new)` we will see `row.names = c(NA, -10L)`.

So if we are copying an integer vector of length 2 from one place to another, regardless of the size of the data, why is it taking longer with larger data frames? The answer to this is what happens when you run:

```r
attr(new, "row.names") <- attr(dat, "row.names")
```

This is syntactic sugar for:

```r
new  <- `attr<-`(new, "row.names", attr(dat, "row.names"))
```

Firstly, this means that we are evaluating the `row.names` for `dat`. Secondly, as [R internals](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html) notes, with a similar example, `` a <- `dim<-`(a, c(7, 2)) ``:

> in principle two copies of `a` exist for the duration of the computation

So this may be happening twice.

#### Where is the evaluation happening?

An easier way to understand this is by printing the right-hand side of that function call.

```r
`attr<-`(new, "row.names", attr(dat, "row.names")) 
# <truncated>
# attr(,"row.names")
#  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

By the time the `row.names` are stored in `new`, the R source code in [attrib.c](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/69b94f0c8ce9b2497f6d7a81922575f6c585b713/src/main/attrib.c#L70), it is clever enough to restore it to `c(NA, n)` form:

```c
INTEGER(val)[0] = NA_INTEGER;
INTEGER(val)[1] = n; // +n:  compacted *and* automatic row names
```

However, the damage is done, the short form `c(NA, -10)` row names were fully evaluated, which as you would expect (and have demonstrated) takes more time for longer vectors of row names.

### Solutions

It is possible to avoid this issue in base R, and also with `data.table` and `tidyverse` packages.

#### base R solution

The main point is - do not copy the row names from one data frame to another. The function suggested by Joris C. to copy any attributes that were not copied by the subset operation, rather than copying all attributes, is a good base R solution.

#### data.table solution

An alternative is to convert the data frame to a `data.table` and using [`data.table::setattr()`](https://rdrr.io/rforge/data.table/man/setattr.html) to set attributes by reference:

```r
library(data.table)
orig <- data.frame(x1 = 1, x2 = 2)
setDT(orig)

mem_location  <- tracemem(orig)

setattr(orig, "foo", TRUE)

tracemem(orig) == mem_location # TRUE

attr(orig, "foo") # TRUE
```

Additionally, with `data.table` you can change the column order by reference so you do not lose the attributes when you reorder the columns:

```r
setcolorder(orig, c(2,1))
attr(orig, "foo") # TRUE

orig
#    x2 x1
# 1:  2  1
```

#### tidyverse solution

Similarly, a `tibble()` keeps its `row.names` attribute when you subset columns:

```r
library(tibble)

set.seed(0)
num_rows  <- 10
dat  <- tibble(
    x_char = sample(letters, num_rows),
    x_int = sample(1:10, num_rows)
) 

attr(dat, "foo")  <- TRUE

new  <- dat[,c(2,1)]

attr(new, "foo") # TRUE
```

I went down several dead-ends with this one, and posted two answers that were not quite right before I understood what was really happening under the hood. But I learned a lot about R in the process. Thanks for asking such an interesting question.

Answer (score 0):

Not a `base` solution but this may be useful nonetheless.

`collapse` package is useful for [fast](https://sebkrantz.github.io/collapse/index.html) transformations like this which retains attributes, similar to the `data.table` approach above. See a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66990649/retain-attributes-and-classes-when-subsetting-rrapply/).

```
orig <- data.frame(x1 = 1, x2 = 2)
attr(orig, "foo") <- TRUE

library(collapse)
new <- collapse::colorderv(orig, c(2, 1)) 
attributes(new)
# $names
# [1] "x2" "x1"
# 
# $class
# [1] "data.frame"
# 
# $row.names
# [1] 1
# 
# $foo
# [1] TRUE
```

With larger data this seems quicker compared to the OP approach:

```
orig <- data.frame(x1 = rep(1, 1e7), x2 = rep(2, 1e7))
attr(orig, "foo") <- TRUE
new <- orig[, c(2, 1)]
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  test = { attributes(new) <- utils::modifyList(attributes(orig), attributes(new)) },
  collapse_approach = {new2 <- collapse::colorderv(orig, c(2, 1))},
  times = 100,
  unit = "ms"  
)
#Unit: milliseconds
#             expr       min         lq        mean     median        uq        max neval cld
#             test 56.264601 57.3118010 63.78885805 58.7479515 59.443000 310.330801   100   b
#collapse_approach  0.007601  0.0126515  0.03835808  0.0535015  0.055301   0.115201   100  a
```